# I want a PHP include to be interrupted

Tags: php, include, switch-statement

Something like this is in a file called "header.php" which all files on my site include:

```
switch (str_replace('/folder_name/','',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])){
    case 'index.php':
    $page_title='main page';
    break;
    case 'page1.php':
    $page_title='page 1 is here';
    break;
    case 'page2.php':
    $page_title='this is page 2';
    break;
}
```

And it's followed by some HTML that's common to all the pages:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
etc...
```

Can I make it so that, for one of the cases in the switch, the include stops right there?  I am asking if there is a way to interrupt an include from within the include.  So for example it might look like:

```
case 'page3.php':
$page_title='the title for page 3';
STOP_THE_INCLUDE
break;
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you exit the switch, use an IF to avoid the rest of the include? Like this:

```
 $stopInclude = false;
 switch (str_replace('/folder_name/','',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])){ 
   case 'index.php': 
     $page_title='main page'; 
     break; 
   case 'page1.php': 
     $page_title='page 1 is here'; 
     break; 
   case 'page2.php': 
     $page_title='this is page 2'; 
     break;
   case 'page3.php': 
     $page_title='the title for page 3'; 
     $stopInclude = true;
     break; 
 }
 if (!$stopInclude) {
   //whole rest of the include
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can simply `return;` inside an include.

Comment: While I agree with your solution, I have to say that interrupting an include from inside one sounds like *horrible* app architecture. (Again, this is nothing against your answer, +1)

Comment: Yeah I don't even think I will keep it set up that way, I was just curious how I would do that if I wanted to.